# Jquery - check if browser supports AJAX to external server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My AJAX is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://www.domain.com',
    data: {mach: stuff},
    success: function(datawohnort) {

    }
});
```

And on domain.com I do:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://wheretherequestcomesfrom.com");
?>
```

It's not working on old browsers, so how could I check with jQuery/js if the browser will support it without making the request to external server?

I'm planning to redirect users who are using a browser that doesn't support CORS to a page that suggests browsers for them to upgrade to.

Comment: $.support.cors. if it is false, cors requests are unsupported. This generally affects all versions of IE older than 10, unless you install a jQuery plugin that adds a transport using the unsupported XDomainRequest syntax.

Comment: Define old browsers? IE 5? Netscape Navigator?

Comment: Are you supporting IE7?? There are plugins that make IE8 work with jQuery.

Comment: I don't want to make it work on old browser but force users to use new browsers ^^ I will redirect them to browser updates. @KevinB why don't you answer normally? I will accept :D

Comment: Which submonkey voted down???? The question is solved so before you down vote, who ever you are, go back to your self-html coding and don't disturb programmers

Comment: @KevinB can you please do normal answer where I can accept? I need some points because of the downvoting animals :(

Comment: *"The question is solved so before you down vote"* haha, no it wasn't. I downvoted before i posted that comment.

Comment: I saw your comment before any downvotes. Why did u downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.support.cors
```

If it is false, cors requests are unsupported. This generally affects all versions of IE older than 10, unless you install a jQuery plugin that adds a transport using the unsupported XDomainRequest syntax.